# How to index nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list as shown below:

```
A = [('a', 'b', 'c'),
     ('d', 'e', 'f'),
     ('g', 'h', 'i')]
```

and I am trying to print the first element of each list using the code:

```
A = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
print A[:][0]
```

But I get the following output:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Required output:

```
('a', 'd', 'g')
```

How to get this output in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A[:]` just creates a copy of the whole list, after which you get element `0` of that copy.

You need to use a list comprehension here:

```
[tup[0] for tup in A]
```

to get a list, or use `tuple()` with a generator expression to get a tuple:

```
tuple(tup[0] for tup in A)
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
>>> [tup[0] for tup in A]
['a', 'd', 'g']
>>> tuple(tup[0] for tup in A)
('a', 'd', 'g')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose a list of lists/tuples with `zip(*list_of_lists)` then select the items you want.

```
>>> a
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> b
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
>>> b[0]
('a', 'd', 'g')
>>> 
>>> c = zip(*a)[0]
>>> c
('a', 'd', 'g')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python lists don't work very well as multi-dimensional arrays.
If you're willing to add an extra dependency(e.g. if you're going to do a lot of array manipulation), `numpy` allows you to use the almost the exact syntax you're looking for

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([('a', 'b', 'c'),
              ('d', 'e', 'f'),
              ('g', 'h', 'i')])
```

---

This outputs the row as an np.array(which can be accessed like a list):

```
>>> A[:,0]
array(['a', 'd', 'g'])
```

---

To get the first row as a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(A[:,0])
('a', 'd', 'g')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
>>> A = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
>>> map(lambda t:t[0], A)
['a', 'd', 'g']
>>> tuple(map(lambda t:t[0],A))
('a', 'd', 'g')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the behavior you want using `pandas` as follows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: A = [('a', 'b', 'c'),
     ('d', 'e', 'f'),
     ('g', 'h', 'i')]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(A)

In [4]: df[:][0]
Out[4]:
0    a
1    d
2    g
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [5]: df[:][0].values
Out[5]: array(['a', 'd', 'g'], dtype=object)
```